# getting started with Fluent nHibernate and asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I thought of using Fluent nhibernate for data access with my asp.net mvc web application...Any good article that describes about the setup of Fluent nHibernate with asp.net MVC web application...

Comment: The first hit will address lots http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Fluent+nhibernate

Comment: and these hits address Asp.net MVC how exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [series](http://www.bengtbe.com/blog/post/2009/08/10/NerdDinner-with-Fluent-NHibernate-Part-1-The-domain-model.aspx) of articles is what I started with. I don't believe it's exactly what I ended up going with, but it's a good start.