# setting up Fluent NHibernate with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I am in search of a tutorial which leads through the setup of Fluent Nhibernate in an asp.net mvc web application... Any good tutorial....

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting started with Fluent nHibernate and asp.net MVC..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011937/getting-started-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/ their official site. :)

Comment: Other tutorial on http://dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/FluentNhibernate,

it do not depend on .net mvc or other. All you need is to create an AutoPersistenceModelGenerator class

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question. Though NHibernate does not depend on MVC, one still needs to know how to use an AutoPersistenceModelGenerator class.